# Python method to extract base64 blob? From logfile, decode and write decoded Json to new file

Tags: python

Hi I have a log file that writes various webtraffic .. some of it in base64.
I would like to be able to scrape the log file and extract the base64 blobs  and decode (in their Json format) then write the output to a new logfile.

Looking for some pointers on where to begin as a novice

Thx

A blob looks like this:

I'd like to capture the data after:

https://open.oneplus.net/cloud/pushdata
    data

#

```
https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/getNearbyAlertDataById
https://cloudconfig.googleapis.com/config
    ?           M»nÓP m?*A+ªT@??_¿?a;©?¸?;N/áÚ¾v?ú?\Û??©##cÅ??ÄX`@ì$>¢#:OéçÆNoÞxýýÙÞ¯ÊÎ¾?Dµ I?Õ`ìádêÕ??zê"ÃQ<D?å?ú¿©îó @hÚu}Á¥xYÞÙu?Ø?qZ?3{ôÕç??m¿Ì­RÿùèÛ»«·Êr°WZ±ÜÕ¡,wKOhAdXÚ#ËC?f_p?}?E.Çr??<??á?÷?f÷ø?X£?à)¶GÕ0
LÑyå§þªòòÖEeëMeëþïª$63p?aN³??âµ6??8Oµ´?¤7F#¸?TÐå#[v?)Mb4e°5
https://mail.google.com/mail/g/
https://mail.google.com/mail/g/
    ?       ãXóa×¥OÚÒÜ«v6y<ùØ/Q8GF??A`ï'-??/Ø
-?  #X+
    êW¦ä¥V*°t1²q¼e¸´äïÆ 2³Ù?RsR?S1
¥
https://open.oneplus.net/oauth/token
    client_secret   cd65b2xxxxxxxf228b7cc61352a1
    scope   write
    grant_type  client_credentials
    client_id   mdmclient0001
https://open.oneplus.net/cloud/pushdata
    data    eyJ0eSI6MSwiZGwiOlt7ImlkIjoiNGJkM2Y4MzEiLCJpbSI6Ijg2NzI5MDAyMjE5OTk0NiIsImJy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-IiwibndoIjpmYWxzZSwibndhIjoiYzA6ZWU6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-IiwibndoIjpmYWxzZSwibndhIjoiYzA6ZWU6ZmI6NWE6NWI6Yzki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-IiwibndoIjpmYWxzZSwibndhIjoiYzA6ZWU6ZmI6NWE6NWI6YzkiLCJud2wiOjAsInR6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    access_token    0de160c6-ed67-42da-9xxx-xxx7cbf150e

    p   âµãÇÇÿÁ:*>Ób?F?Câ?)ñ£"?¢£û3
    ?       íØ{PT×ð{ÎÂîå
e÷ªéµ½¥ÚZÔ?eXÈ ?E?ñÁËg§??Ýl?Ýí>D?ÉµRê+?hzEbZEC"!£"%d|áuð?ï¨Ñ{~G|EÚIëL:í¸|Ø  {öÜß}ìþ¸_özaÍ>ï?Å,?xï0?^§PGèô]¨Iª×?ÎÜpc¨Ë¨>ßæ­eB?   ?ÊZKw®]þP?zpª±6)1Çãâ}Æ???????%¢?ÌïßÇ??^4gDZB"Í¢Ál?Ó?
    ³!D/hS????2Ô¨d/"öá??½y·Ð?-¿GX÷?P
```

Comment: please post a portion of the log file, to see what we are dealing with.

Comment: question updated with example